# Why can't dopamine cross the blood brain barrier but l-dopa can?

Tags: neurology

Levodopa can cross the BBB and is less lipid soluble then dopamine, so dopamine should be able to cross the BBB more easily then l-dopa, but for some reason dopamine cant cross the BBB. Both dl-methamphetamine and levomethamphetamine can cross the blood brain barrier, but why not dl-dopamine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [L-Dopa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-DOPA) and [Dopamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine) are polar molecules and thus hydrophilic. They are solvable in water but not in lipids, so they are not able to cross the [Blood-brain barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood%E2%80%93brain_barrier) on their own.

The difference is that L-Dopa has a [transport protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterodimeric_amino-acid_transporter) ([SLC7A5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLC7A5)) that allows it to pass through the Blood-brain barrier, whereas dopamine doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, that's LAT1, but why doesn't DAT1 have any​ effect?

Comment: If you look at the [distribution of LAT1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterodimeric_amino-acid_transporter) versus the [distribution of DAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine_transporter#Location_and_distribution) you can see that LAT1 is distributed in the blood-brain barrier, whereas DAT is not.